# React-native(EXPO) open files

Tags: react-native, pdf, expo

I'm downloading PDF files using Expo.FileSystem.downloadAsync. How can I open it? I found solution to eject EXPO, and then using native... But this is not very suitable for my decision.
How can I open this files? Maby with some other app, that device storing for pdf files? I will consider any suggestions. Is it possible to somehow convert pdf files to another format, if it is convenient then to open them in the react-native app? I have not been able to find a solution to this problem for a week...
I found https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking , but it's working only online, if i got it right, but I need to open this files even offline, without internet connection. And I cant connect it now. It's needed to make eject too?
I would be very grateful for the help.

Comment: Hi, with Expo you use this package: https://github.com/xcarpentier/rn-pdf-reader-js

Answer (score 3):

There is simply no such possibility at the moment ... I disable expo and used native libraries